# Troubleshooting a Record Sharing Mystery

Tags: sharing, platform-bug

**Update: Totally rewriting/simplifying this question now that I've zero'ed in on the core issue.**

I'm sharing an Account, **Program B** with a public group called **Access Program B's Data**.  As part of that account sharing record, I'm including Read/Write access to all cases linked to that account.  (For the curious, this sharing record is set up in an account trigger which is working properly; the sharing record exists with all the correct settings):

[image]

However, not all of the related cases are being shared properly.

- For most of our cases at this desk, the sharing works correctly.  Members of **Access Program B's Data** have access to the case records as expected.  For these cases, when you click "Sharing" on the Case record, there's an account sharing record as one would expect: [image]
- On other cases, the sharing is not working.  Members of the public group do not have access, and no account sharing line shows up in the sharing list.  Curiously, all of the cases which are not sharing properly are owned by queues (rather than by users) -- but there are other cases, also owned by queues, which are sharing properly.

**UPDATE:**  This appears to be a platform bug.  Changing the owner of the affected cases, and then changing it back forces a recalculation and resolves the issue.  SFDC support is looking into the problem, and I'll let people here know if there's any useful information when it's resolved.

Comment: For the cases P can't access, are you sure there's a sharing row on the account? Also, what org wide defaults are set on case?

Comment: Case is default private.  For the cases P can't access, yes, positive there's a sharing row on the account.  I've verified it's the same account for both!

Comment: Is there any pattern in the queues that do and don't get the sharing rule? And is there possibly a pattern in the Case data? E.g. cases linked to an Asset or Contact behave differently from cases linked to the Account only?

Comment: UPDATE: This appears to be a platform bug. Changing the owner of the affected cases, and then changing it back forces a recalculation and resolves the issue. SFDC support is looking into the problem, and I'll let people here know if there's any useful information when it's resolved.

Comment: Congrats on finding the answer! You should probably mark this question as answered (I have no idea how) by you, so that it falls out of the "unanswered" question queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a platform bug. Changing the owner of the affected cases, and then changing it back forces a recalculation and resolves the issue. SFDC support is looking into the problem, and I'll let people here know if there's any useful information when it's resolved.